# Reading data from MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-java-driver

I am quit new to MongoDB.
I have a collection with few documents inside. Below is a example for that.

```
 {"UserID": "1", "Name": "John", "Marks":40} 
 {"UserID": "2", "Name": "Mark", "Marks":50} 
 {"UserID": "3", "Name": "Jesse", "Marks":60}
```

I want to get the marks of all the entries to an array to display them and to do some calculations using java.
so far I have done the blow to read the document and display all the data. But I couldn't find a way to get only the "Marks" out of it.

```
 MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost",27017); 
 DB db = client.getDB( "test_db" );
 DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("AllocatedMarks");

 DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
 while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
 }
```

This all I know about reading data from MongoDB using Java so far. Please help me to get only the marks field from the document to an array.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass key to the get() method, so you can do this way:

```
for(int i=0; i<cursor.size();i++){
   System.out.println(cursor.get(i).get("Marks"));
}
```

Similarly using foreach loop you can do...

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. This will do.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to get the "Marks":

```
DBObject dbObject;
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
   dbObject = cursor.next();
   int marks = ((Number)dbObject.get("Marks")).intValue()
}
```

You may be able to cast directly to an Integer instead of a Number.

Not important, but if you wanted to only load the "Marks" you could issue your query as so:

```
BasicDBObject fieldsDBObject = new BasicDBObject();
fieldsDBObject.append("Marks",true);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(null, fieldsDBObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the `get()` method in DBCursor object.
Use it as

```
System.out.println(cursor.next().get("Marks");
```

Refer MongoDB api for details.
[DBCursor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html) , [DBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBObject.html) , [BSONObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/BSONObject.html)